ticks in seaborn dark plot
I have made a plot with sns.axes_style("dark"). I want to put ticks on this plot, in the same way that the default style has ticks. Moreover, the scale of both axes is logarithmic and I would like the ticks that correspond to powers of 10 to be bigger than the others. I would also like the tick marks to be inside the frame and not outside of it.
I have found no built-in method to do any of the above. The only thing that I can do is put a grid, but this is clearly far from what I want. If I am right and there is indeed no "easy" way to do it, how else can I do it?

You can show the ticks via ax.tick_params(bottom=True, left=True). ax.set_xscale('log') sets a log scale.
ax.tick_params(..., direction='in') changes the direction of the ticks from the default 'out' to 'in' ('inout' would be in both directions).
By default, ax.tick_params() only modifies the "major" ticks. To include the "minor" ticks: ax.tick_params(..., which='both'). On a logarithmic scale by default major ticks are set for the powers of 10, and minor ticks for their multiples (with a shorter tick mark and without a label).
You can call ax.tickparams() multiple times with different parameters, e.g. to only change the length (or the color) of the major ticks.
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_style("dark")
x = np.logspace(0, 4, num=500)
y = np.arctan(x)
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y)
ax.tick_params(which='both', direction='in', bottom=True, left=True)
ax.set_xscale('log')


PS: You can also enable the ticks via the rc-parameters ("rc" stands for "runtime configuration"):
sns.set_style('dark', rc={'xtick.bottom': True, 'ytick.left': True}). This shows the ticks for all following plots, until you restart or change these parameters in another way.  ax.tick_params() only has effect on the given subplot.

This was very helpful. How do I put the tick marks inside the frame and not outside of it? Also, how do I include tick marks for the intermediate values, making sure that the ticks which correspond to powers of 10 are more pronounced?
